# How can trailing spaces be removed from CSV import?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
1 ,A ,a 
2 ,B ,b 
99,ZZ,zz
```

How can I import the CSV so that the trailing spaces are removed?

Comment: How did you try importing it?

Comment: Could you not open each cell and strip the whitespace, and resave?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use `strip()` on each of the columns as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input:    
    for row in csv.reader(f_input):
        row = [col.strip() for col in row]

        print row
```

This would print:

```
['1', 'A', 'a']
['2', 'B', 'b']
['99', 'ZZ', 'zz']
```

The `csv` library does provide an option called [`skipinitialspace=True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) but this will only deal with leading spaces.

Comment: Upvote for most Pythonic and using correct packages.

Answer (score 1):

For a given string `field`, you can clear trailing whitespace by using `field.strip()`. `rstrip()` and `lstrip` strip left and right whitespaces.

So, import the file:

```
with open("file.csv","r") as csv_file:
    csv_data = csv_file.read()

lines = csv_data.split("\n")
for line in lines:
    line = line.split(",") #Or whatever delimiter you have



    #The stripped line looks like this:
    for field in line:
        print(field.strip())
```

Comment: You can't apply .strip() directly to a list.  You have to apply to string.

Comment: Ah yes, typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Read a CSV (or Excel file) using Pandas and trim it using this custom function.

```
#Definition for strippping whitespace
def trim(dataset):
    trim = lambda x: x.strip() if type(x) is str else x
    return dataset.applymap(trim)
```

You can now apply trim(CSV/Excel) to your code like so (as part of a loop, etc.)

```
dataset = trim(pd.read_csv('__.csv'))
```